# Delete Record from Database row wise in Android

Tags: android, database

I'm trying to build my first Android application, but I'm experiencing a problem: I write following code for insert record in database, but I don't know how to delete a row, so can anybody help me???
Code for insert record:

```
public void btnAddEmp_Click(View view)
{
    boolean ok=true;
    try
    {
        Spannable spn=txtAge.getText();
        String name=txtName.getText().toString();
        int age=Integer.valueOf(spn.toString());
        int deptID=Integer.valueOf((int)spinDept.getSelectedItemId());
        Student emp=new Student(name,age,deptID);

        dbHelper.AddEmployee(emp);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ok=false;
        CatchError(ex.toString());
    }
    finally
    {
        if(ok)
        {
            //NotifyEmpAdded();
            Alerts.ShowEmpAddedAlert(this);
            txtEmps.setText("Number of students "+String.valueOf(dbHelper.getEmployeeCount()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE fieldName = value
```

This is delete query. Execute it with `execSql`

Edit: use `execSql` instead of `rawQuery`

Comment: rawQuery is meant for querying ..not for doing modifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this using [SQLiteDatabase.execSQL()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) and don't try *rawQuery* It's meant for querying.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

db.execSQL("DELETE FROM tableName where fieldName=Value"); 

db.close();
```

Check out the detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31044699/730807)

Comment: This query will delete the entire table contents. The question was asked how to delete row wise